# Google Search Doesn't list the app, after migrating to firebase

Tags: android, google-app-indexing

In our current play store build, when a query is searched, if the story present, it lists our app in search results. But in the latest code, we are using `play services version 9.0.0`  and using `firebase`. After adding these changes, our app is not listed in the search results. Is there any rule that only play store build will appear in search results ?
 `Auto Complete Textview` is working fine. On clicking the suggestion, it launches our app. Also, I have tested the app in below cases:

```
1. From terminal 
2. Using Bar Code Scanner App
3. Changing Edit Configurations -> Launch(Url selected) and pasted the deeplink url
```

In all 3 cases, it worked fine and launched the app. Even AutoComplete Textview is also working fine. Only our app is not listed in search suggessions both in Google App and Chrome. But same query shows our app, when playstore build is installed.

Below is my root `build.gradle` :

```
 dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        }


app module build.gradle :

dependencies{
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also, added the `google-services.json` in the app directory

This is my appIndexing Activity:

```
        <activity
            android:name="packagename.deeplinking.ui.GoogleSearchIndexingActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="hostname"
                    android:scheme="custom_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I followed the instruction given in the below links and integrated App indexing API as suggested.

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/
2. https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/app-indexing#1